# Mechanical dimensions from points

Tags: javascript, php, drawing, cad

[image]

1. How to draw the line (blue) from 2D vertices (automatically adding edges)?
2. How to add mechanical dimensions (black)?

I could use PHP to draw the 1. Anyone knows any library or hint for doing the 2. (for instance in JS)?

**Some insights:**

The mechanical dimensions can only be horizontal or vertical. They should however be able to snap first onto the vertices, and secondly onto the cross-sections of the edge and itself (red circles). I am also thinking about possibility of doing this in some CAD software, but how to make edges automatically from the imported points?

Comment: You could use SVG to create the visible effects in php or JavaScript. For JavaScript: http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PHP or JS? I am discouraged at helping you with that if you are also OK with doing it in a CAD.

Comment: @user152807 PHP and JS are things that I can use. CAD is mentioned, becuase I am looking for the possibilities. If there was a CAD software, that could automatically connect imported points as a polygon, then the problem is solved without programming.

Comment: i see you don't need this generated in an http request, so the tools you've suggested are wrong. you may want to re-tag your question to gnuplot, or better yet try it out

Comment: @user152807 well, I am better in drawing pictures with PHP. Besides, the data needs to get into the apllication from outside.

Comment: ok, but you haven't shared any code yet, so it seems you are asking for a complete solution i.e. you won't be doing it

Comment: @user152807 I am just looking for possible approaches that are leading to the solution, not the complete solution. Any tips appreciated.